# С прописной или со строчной ИТАЛЬЯНСКИЕ пьяцца и виа?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Дело в том, что а Инете разнобой... Начала было всё к чертям понижать, но как-то их (прописных) подозрительно много...

Площадь и улица, если кто не знает.

> ...от северных ворот города с Пьяцца дель Пополо до папской базилики
>   Санта Мария Маджоре. Сегодня эта улица для удобства разбита названиями
>   на несколько отрезков: Виа Систина, Виа алле Куатро Фонтане (нашлось
>   только: Сан-Карло алле Куатро Фонтане), Виа Агостино Депретис, Виа
>   дель Эсквилино, Виа Карло Альберто, Виа Конте Верде, виа (будем
>   думать, что делать с пьяцца и виа...) Санта-Кроче-ин-Джерусалемме.
>   Северная граница современного района Монти лежит на пересечении Виа
>   алле Куатро Фонтане и виа дель Квиринале.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пьяцца** — нескл., ж (в названиях площадей итальянских городов), напр.: Пьяцца Навона (в Риме), Пьяцца Сан Марко (в Венеции)…

Орфографический словарь русского языка

[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/145805/пьяцца](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/145805/%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%86%D0%B0)

Всё зависит от стиля текста.

В путеводителях обычно пишется прописная буква: **Пьяцца Претория** — одна из центральных площадей Палермо, расположенная по оси улицы Македа к востоку от Кватро Канти.

В других случаях можно встретить оба варианта, при этом в текстах может присутствовать слово "пьяцца", которого нет в словаре:

Они сидели в открытом баре "Коломбо" **на Пьяцца Навона**... [Александра Маринина. Иллюзия греха (1996)]

Будто карнавальная толпа хлынула сюда **с пьяцца Сан-Марко**  [Дина Рубина. Медная шкатулка (сборник) (2015)]

Маленькая удобная марина, уютная **пьяцца,** пустынная (не сезон) набережная… [Дина Рубина. (2014)]

Снимали в Риме, на **Пьяцца ди Навона.** [Эльдар Рязанов. Подведенные итоги (2000)]

Comment: А с Виа-то что? Плакайу... Т_Т

Comment: По-моему, всё то же самое.  В словаре слова нет, и вряд ли оно там появится.  Но смысл его понятен, поэтому в путеводителях обычно используется официальный вариант, а в художественной литературе  считается допустимой строчная буква, наряду с прописной.  Примеры: Одним из таких мест можно назвать улицу Виа Венето (Via Veneto), одну из главных «туристических» артерий города.Профессор жил недалеко от площади Венеции, на via Bassina. [Наталья Александрова. Последний ученик да Винчи (2010)]

Answer (score 1):

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Слово *Пьяцца*, употребляемое в названиях площадей итальянских городов, пишется с прописной буквы без кавычек: *Пьяцца Гранде, Пьяцца Навона*.

Правило.
1. Проспекты, улицы, площади, переулки, тупики, мосты и т. п.

В этих названиях все слова, кроме родовых (аллея, бульвар, линия, набережная, переулок, площадь, проезд, просек, проспект, спуск, тупик, улица, шоссе), рекомендуется писать с прописной буквы по общему правилу написания географических названий, например:
Комсомольский проспект, проспект Мира; улица Бутырский Вал, улица Каретный Ряд, улица Кузнецкий Мост, улица Лихоборские Бугры, Пушкинская улица, улица Народного Ополчения, улица Серпуховской Заставы, улица Сивцев Вражек, улица Теплый Стан, улица Тюфелева Роща, Елисейские Поля (улица в Париже); площадь Крестьянской Заставы, Никитские Ворота, площадь Революции; Большой Козихинский переулок, Кривоколенный переулок; Сытинский тупик; Большой Каменный мост, мост Вздохов; Ростовская набережная; шоссе Энтузиастов.

Comment: Серж! Поищите, пожалуйста, и про виа! Ваша "Справка" противоречит себе: "В этих названиях все слова, кроме родовых (аллея, бульвар, линия, набережная, переулок, ***площадь***, проезд, просек, проспект, спуск, тупик, ***улица***, шоссе), рекомендуется писать с прописной буквы..."

Comment: Где именно она противоречит? Это по материалам Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П. Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию. Издание четвертое, исправленное.- М.: "ЧеРо", 2001
Мильчин А.Э., Чельцова Л.К. Справочник издателя и автора. Редакционно-издательское оформление издания. 2-е издание, исправленное и дополненное. М.: ОЛМА-Пресс, 2003.

Comment: http://doc-style.ru/SPR/?id=1.24

Comment: Вия - это название итальянской улицы?

Comment: Вы ведь по-русски пишете. Либо площадь дель Пополо, либо Пьяцца дель Пополо, где Пьяцца - часть названия. Нет в русском такого родового слова *пьяцца*.

Comment: В русском языке -площадь - родовое наименование. Следовательно - строчная. в итальянском языке Пьяцца - площадь - входит в название, а не употреблено в качестве родового названия. Поэтому прописная.

Comment: Никаких противоречий.

Comment: Серж, виа = улица. М_Г, а как же ответ Справки у Сержа? О_о

Comment: В названиях иноязычных, состоящих из нескольких слов, с прописной буквы пишутся и родовые наименования, если они не вошли в русский язык в качестве нарицательных. Например: Йошкар-Ола ( ола - гора), Рио-Нееро, Рио-Гранде ( рио - река), Маточкин Шар ( шар - пролив), Рю-де-ля - Пе ( рю - улица), но: Сырдаръя, Амударъя ( дарья - река), Каракумы ( кумы - пески), Нордкап ( кап - мыс), поскольку название пишется в одно слово.

Comment: Серж, спасибо за последний коммент.

Comment: С маленькой буквы не переведённые родовые наименования пишутся в конечной части сложных слов, образованных _через дефис_, например, в наименованиях улиц английского происхождения: **Бейкер-стрит** и т. п. Отдельное же слово со значением родового наименования без перевода остаётся полноправной частью имени топонима, поэтому и пишется с большой.